# The difference : When / Before

Tags: conjunctions

1. I had gotten used to coffee, **when** I went on a trip to Brazil to try many different types of coffee.

I think this implies that I went to Brazil **immediatly** after I had gotten used to coffee. And **When** is the same as **and it was that moment that~**. When we mean this by when, we put **comma**. I feel like I can say **when** instead of **before**, when to emphasize the immediacy.

2. I had gotten used to coffee, **before** I went on a trip to Brazil to try many different types of coffee

I think **before** is only talking about the time sequence without implying anything. **Before** means **and it was after that moment that~**. When we mean this we should put **comma**.

Do you guys think I tell the difference right?

Comment: Would you please explain a bit more on context? The relationship/connection between two events, "get used to coffee" and "go on a trip"? Is the former considered as a condition/trigger/reason of the latter?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written these sentences is incorrect grammatically, but you are correct about the difference between them. You need to move **when** to the very beginning to make an [introductory phrase](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/commas-after-introductory-phrases/):

> 1. **When** I had gotten used to coffee, I went on a trip to Brazil to try many different types.

For the second sentence, remove the comma.

> I had gotten used to coffee **before** I went on a trip to Brazil to try many different types.

We don't place a comma here because now "I had gotten used to coffee" is the **main clause**. You could also write,

> Before I went on a trip to Brazil to try many different types, I had gotten used to coffee.

And now you see the comma again.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the context.

## context#1: fascinated

Assume you love coffee very much, the only reason you went to Brazil is coffee. You could say

> When I **had gotten** used to coffee, I went on a trip to Brazil to try many different types.

To emphasize the fact that you're so fascinated with coffee that you were impatient to wait more, You could say

> When I **got** used to coffee, I went on a trip to Brazil to try many different types.

## context#2: prepared

Assume you're NOT that much fascinated with coffee, or the coffee is not the only reason to went to Brazil. Maybe you went to Brazil to visit friends or family. To emphasize the fact that you'd **already** gotten used to coffee, you were **already** prepared before that trip, you could say

> Before I went on a trip to Brazil to try many different types, I had gotten used to coffee.